# How to add simple account|login links where login changes to logout when signed in?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account

I deleted the default RWD account icon with dropdown as I didn't want it.

Instead I want two simple links in my header: one which says account that simply takes you to the account page, then one that says login which changes to log out when the customer is logged in.

[image]

For a better idea of what I am looking to do see the attached image.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: Just detect if the user is logged in using `Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()` and change the text accordingly

Comment: Thank you for the answer but how would I go about adding the links in the first place? I am quite new to magento development unfortunately

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I normally go with template approach.

```
   <div class="account-links">
        <?php
        if ($this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()) {
            ?>
            <a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('customer/account'); ?>">Account</a>
            <a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('customer/account/logout'); ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Log out'); ?></a>
        <?php } else {
            ?>
            <a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login'); ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Log in'); ?></a>
            <span> or</span>
            <a href="<?php echo Mage::getUrl('customer/account/create'); ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Register'); ?></a>
        <?php } ?>
   </div>
```

Stick the above in a template file your themes header.phtml file

Comment: Thanks very much! does it matter where I put it in header.phtml?

Comment: Ok it worked but appeared underneath my nav for some reason. As seen here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/171478031/Screen%20Shot%202016-04-13%20at%2016.34.53.png

Any idea how to move it above the nav at the top right? thanks

Comment: You will need to place it above <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?> within your header.phtml file

Answer (score 0):

Go to **app/design/frontend/default/your-theme/layout**

Then find the .xml files according to the toplinks you want to change

**customer.xml for "My Account, Login, Logout and My Wishlist"**`

```
<reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label>
        <url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/> <title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position>
        </action>
</reference>
```

There you'll have something with which you can work, you'll just need to adapt it to your needs.